# Is my socket connection dropping some data sent over it?

Tags: java, sockets, gson, locking, race-condition

I'm writing a `Connection` class that sends and receives data going both ways via `Command`s and `CommandResult`s. However, when multiple requests are sent quickly over the `Connection`, some do not make it through properly.

It sound like a race condition of sorts, but I feel like I've prepared for that by:

- Locking and unlocking writes to the socket,
- having a table of sent `Command`s whose `CommandResult`s haven't been received,
- and locking and unlocking changes to said table.

`Command`s are received and processed on a single thread, so that shouldn't be the issue.

I've looked over the code enough times that I feel like the problem has to be elsewhere, but my team is very confident that `Connection` is the culprit.

This sample is a little long, but this was as small as I feel I could make a complete example. I did make sure it was well documented though. The important things to know are:

- `AwaitWrapper`s are just a Future. Getting the resource will block until it is actually filled in,
- `Message`s just wrap requests and responses,
- a `Serializer` is basically a gson wrapper,
- `Command`s and `CommandResult`s are tracked with a common UUID,
- and `ICommandHandler`s take in a `Command` and output a `CommandResult`. The contents of `Command`s and `CommandResult`s shouldn't matter for this.

Connection.java:

```java
public class Connection {

    private Socket socket;
    private ICommandHandler handler;
    private Serializer ser;
    private Lock resultsLock;
    private Lock socketWriteLock;
    private Map<UUID,AwaitWrapper<CommandResult>> reservations;

    public Connection(Socket socket) {
        ser = new Serializer();
        reservations = new TreeMap<UUID,AwaitWrapper<CommandResult>>();
        handler = null;
        this.socket = socket;

        // Set up locks
        resultsLock = new ReentrantLock();
        socketWriteLock = new ReentrantLock();
    }

    public Connection(String host, int port) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        socket = new Socket(host, port);
        ser = new Serializer();
        reservations = new TreeMap<UUID,AwaitWrapper<CommandResult>>();
        handler = null;

        // Set up locks
        resultsLock = new ReentrantLock(true);
        socketWriteLock = new ReentrantLock(true);
    }


    /* Sends a command on the socket, and waits for the response
     *
     * @param com The command to be sent
     * @return The Result of the command operation.
     */
    public CommandResult sendCommand(Command com) {
        try {
            AwaitWrapper<CommandResult> delayedResult = reserveResult(com);
            write(new Message(com));

            CommandResult res = delayedResult.waitOnResource();
            removeReservation(com);
            return res;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    /* Sets handler for incoming Commands. Also starts listening to the socket
     *
     * @param handler The handler for incoming Commands
     */
    public void setCommandHandler(ICommandHandler handler) {
        if (handler == null) return;
        this.handler = handler;
        startListening();
    }

    /* Starts a thread that listens to the socket
     *
     * Note: don't call this until handler has been set!
     */
    private void startListening() {
        Thread listener = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (receiveMessage());
                handler.close();
            }
        };
        listener.start();
    }

    /* Recives all messages (responses _and_ results) on a socket
     *
     * Note: don't call this until handler has been set!
     *
     * @return true if successful, false if error
     */
    private boolean receiveMessage() {
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = socket.getInputStream();

            Message message = (Message)ser.deserialize(in, Message.class);
            if (message == null) return false;

            if (message.containsCommand()) {
                // Handle receiving a command
                Command com = message.getCommand();
                CommandResult res = handler.handle(com);
                write(new Message(res));

            } else if (message.containsResult()) {
                // Handle receiving a result
                CommandResult res = message.getResult();
                fulfilReservation(res);
            } else {
                // Neither command or result...?
                return false;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    //--------------------------
    // Thread safe IO operations

    private void write(Message mes) throws IOException {
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        socketWriteLock.lock();
        ser.serialize(out, mes);
        socketWriteLock.unlock();
    }


    //----------------------------------
    //Thread safe reservation operations

    private AwaitWrapper<CommandResult> reserveResult(Command com) {
        AwaitWrapper<CommandResult> delayedResult = new AwaitWrapper<CommandResult>();

        resultsLock.lock();
        reservations.put(com.getUUID(), delayedResult);
        resultsLock.unlock();

        return delayedResult;
    }

    private void fulfilReservation(CommandResult res) {
        resultsLock.lock();
        reservations.get(res.getUUID()).setResource(res);
        resultsLock.unlock();
    }

    private void removeReservation(Command com) {
        resultsLock.lock();
        reservations.remove(com.getUUID());
        resultsLock.unlock();
    }


    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    // A Message wraps both commands and results for easy deserialization

    private class Message {
        ...
    }
}
```

When monitoring the receiving side of the `Connection`, the handler never gets triggered for some of the `Command`s sent. It should be triggered by and process every incoming `Command`.

I'm considering ditching the reservation table and locking writes to the socket until the the response has been received, but I'm expecting that that won't come without significant performance penalties.

Am I missing some crucial step that would prevent race conditions?

---

**EDIT:** Adding the `Serializer` and `ICommandHandler` classes for those who are curious.

Serializer.java:

```java
public class Serializer {

    private Gson gson;

    public Serializer() {
        gson = new Gson();
    }

    public Object deserialize(InputStream is, Class type) throws IOException {
        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        reader.setLenient(true);
        if (reader.hasNext()) {
            Object res = gson.fromJson(reader, type);
            return res;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void serialize(OutputStream os, Object obj) throws IOException {
        JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        gson.toJson(obj, obj.getClass(), writer);
        writer.flush();
    }
}
```

ICommandHandler:

```java
public interface ICommandHandler {
    public CommandResult handle(Command com);
    public void close();
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the `reader.hasNext()` test. It is causing you to mss every message following the one that caused it to return false. Just let your code block in the read. There is no need for any of these per-socket semaphores. You're making s mountain out of a molehill here.

Comment: I wasn't sure what gson would return if it was just let to serialize a closed input stream. In the interest of more understandable behavior, the code checks that there is a valid json object, and then deserializes it. I fully acknowledge that there is probably a better solution out there, but I want this to work before I iterate on it.

Comment: IOW you want to keep all the existing bugs before you ever fix them. Not currently having a complete objext to deserialize isn't the same thing as a closed input stream. You can absolutely rely on detecting that, one way or another. You dont have to invent your own handling for it.

Comment: Fair point. I was just trying to avoid making too many changes while trying to solve this problem specifically. Just trying to reduce chaos I guess haha

Comment: So you want to solve this problem but not by making any changes. Not much sense being talked here.

Answer (score -1):

The locks do nothing in your case, there is no race-condition there, if the same handler is used for multiple sockets then the locks need to be inside the handler, you're using a single-threaded client so locks do nothing there, Note: when using locks use a `try-finally`.
If you're just starting with Sockets you probably don't know this but [SocketChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html) is a lot more efficient than the Socket class which is extremely old.
I can't help you more than that without seeing `Serializer` and `ICommandHandler`.
It is most likely a problem in the `Serializer`.

Comment: The locks are so that two threads from the Command-sending side cannot write to the socket at the same time. Are we sure that they don't matter in that case?

Comment: If you think that it would be useful, I can include my `Serializer` and `ICommandHandler`, I was just wary of including too much code.

Comment: `SocketChannel` isn't even slightly 'more efficient that the `Socket` class', but it is amenable to non-blocking I/O and scalability via `Selector.select()`. Don't confuse the issue.

Comment: First: Locks are not needed, as long as you don't write outside the listening thread.
Second: @user207421 `SocketChannel` with non-blocking I/O is faster than `Socket` with the thread-per-client model, also `SocketChannel` uses `ByteBuffer` which can use direct memory which is faster then heap memory https://www.evanjones.ca/software/java-bytebuffers.html.
Third: If you to simplify good performance and don't use android you can use https://github.com/OughtToPrevail/AsyncNetwork which is a library I made but it does over-simplify things so don't use it if you want to learn `Socket`s well.

Comment: @OughtToPrevail Non-blocking I/O isn't faster, it is just non-blocking. Channels with direct byte buffers can be faster if they use native memory *and* the data is never brought into Java memory, e.g. copying between a socket and a file. Otherwise there is no basis to either claim, or the OP's. The general purpose of NIO is not performance *per se* but scalability.

Comment: @user207421 Non-blocking I/O is indeed faster, for example if you write a big buffer, blocking I/O will most likely not complete the write whereas non-blocking I/O will complete sending the whole buffer. Also non-blocking I/O allows you to read and write parallel whereas if you want to do the same with blocking I/O you have to leave the current thread. Instead of saying all of this, I said "performance". And yes for scalability it does beat `Socket` by a lot.